# Use gitlab's "needs:" to skip a stage

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to achieve the following in a gitlab CI pipeline:

```
build_diagrams  --+--  build_docs  -----  deploy_web
                  |
                  \---------------------  deploy_wiki
```

There are 3 stages, the first two build stuff, the last deploys the results on webpages. There are two products to be deployed, one is the result of the first build step, the other needs a dependent intermediate build step. I have tried the following:

```
stages:
  - build
  - docs
  - deploy

build_diagrams:
  stage: build
  ...

build_docs:
  stage: docs
  ...

deploy_web:
  stage: deploy
  ...

deploy_wiki:
  stage: deploy
  needs: ["build_diagrams"]
  ...
```

I am doing this so that the `deploy_wiki` step is run even if `build_docs` fials. Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

[image: failed pipeline]

How can I do this? (I haven't been able to find any example for such a rather simple use-case.)

Comment: Try to set    
allow_failure: true   
 for build_docs

Comment: This works -- but do I then need the `needs:` at all? Or better: I would prefer to have the execution of the `deploy_wiki` job only depend on the outcome of the job it needs the output of and not have to disable the check whether other jobs are failing to make it run.